# Where does the prior distribution $p(z)$ for adversarial autoencoders come from?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

I am trying to understand how an adversarial autoencoder works. The discriminator takes as an input the aggregated posterior $q(z)$ generated from the decoder and matches this against the prior distribution $p(z)$ which is the true distribution from the input data.

What I do not understand is how the prior distribution $p(z)$ is calculated. The original paper repeatedly refers to it as an 'arbitrary prior distribution' a term I'm not familiar with. Looking at implementations of AAE on github, it seems people generally assume $p(z)$ follows a normal distribution. I cannot understand why we would have this assumption, and furthermore why we would want to impose this onto the network.

Comment: As the paper says, the distribution can be arbitrary (i.e. chosen by you). What distribution you choose depends on what you want to model.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but what I don't understand is how I would know prior what distribution would be suitable for my data. Isn't this what my AAE is supposed to be learning?

Comment: No, the AAE does not learn that (at least in standard formulations). It is basically a hyperparameter.